# How to refresh aws cognito session on android after 1 hour

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I have been reading around on different ways to refresh the cognito session after 1 hour, and I have yet to get a conclusive answer from aws team or anyone else. How do you get new tokens after the sessions have expired without re-authenticating, that is, the user has to login again (enter their password/email credentials).

There is a method `refresh()` in `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` class, that I believe refreshes the session. However, after that is called how do you get the new tokens (`idToken`/`accessToken`/`refreshToken`)? In my case the `refreshToken` is set to the maximum expiration time which is about 10 years.

The only way to get new tokens as I have done so far, is through user authentication when the user is logging in, where `cognitoUser.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler)` is called. This interface provides the tokens retrieved from `CognitioUserSession`. It seems very counterproductive for my application in particular to prompt the user to login, using their password each time after 1 hour.

I would like to add one more thing, is it even possible to get new tokens after the `idToken` and `accessToken` have expired? Looking at the aws cognito raw code, I have not seen an interface that provides that outside of login in the user despite what the documentation says.